Proving that convergence of norms and convergence a.e. implies strong convergence
I have in my notes the following theorem

Theorem
$(Y,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ $\sigma-$finite measure space, $p\geqslant 1$, $\{f_n\}\subset L^p(Y)$ sequence of functions, $f\in L^p(Y)$ such that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=f(x)\quad\mathrm{a.e.}$$
(a.e. pointwise convergence). Then,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}||f_n||_{L^p(X)}=||f||_{L^p(X)}$$
implies strong convergence in $L^p(X)$.

and I want to understand the proof I was given. My notes use Vitali convergence theorem and while I have no trouble understanding and proving the requirements concerning absolute continuity, my notes skip the proof of convergence in measure, so I would appreciate to have some feedback. How do I prove that, within the hypotheses of the theorem above,
$$\{f_n\}\to f\quad\text{in measure}$$ (note that the finite-measure case is trivial due to Severini-Egorov theorem, since convergence a.e. implies almost uniform convergence, which implies convergence in measure)?

Let $\{Y_n\}$ be an increasing sequence of sets such that $n\le \mu(Y_n)<\infty$ and $\bigcup Y_n=Y$. Let $0<\varepsilon<1$ chosen arbitrarily. By uniform absolute continuity, there exists $k$ such that
$$\sup_n\int_{Y\setminus Y_k} |f_n|^p<\varepsilon$$
and by pointwise convergence and Fatou we get
$$\int_{Y\setminus Y_k} |f|^p<\varepsilon$$
as well.
By Egorov, we can find $B_k$ such that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $B_k$ and $\mu(Y_k\setminus B_k)<\varepsilon$
Hence
$$\mu(|f_n-f|>\varepsilon')=\mu(|f_n-f|>\varepsilon'\cap Y_k)+\mu(|f_n-f|>\varepsilon'\cap (Y\setminus Y_k)).$$
The first term in the RHS is eventually less than $\mu(Y_k\setminus B_k)<\varepsilon,$ while for the second term we apply Chebychev's inequality:
$$\mu(|f_n-f|>\varepsilon'\cap (Y\setminus Y_k))\le \frac{1}{\varepsilon'^p}\int_{Y\setminus Y_k}|f_n-f|^p\le 2^p\frac{\varepsilon}{\varepsilon'^p}.$$
Hence if we choose $\varepsilon\le \tilde\varepsilon{\varepsilon'}^p2^{-p}$, we get
$$\lim_n \mu(|f_n-f|>\varepsilon')<2\tilde \varepsilon.$$
Since $\tilde \varepsilon$ was chosen arbitrarily, the result follows.

I have a question. Do you think that it would be correct to use the uniform absolute continuity of the integral functions of ${|f_n|^p}$ (which I proved independently) and the absolute continuity of the integral function of $|f|^p$ to infer the uniform absolute continuity of the integral functions of ${|f_n-f|^p}$, so that I can use that to deal with the second term?
